# MS-Access keeps stealing focus from VBA

Tags: vba, sql-server, microsoft-access

When I'm working on MS Access VBA scripting, the Access application keeps stealing focus from VBA, even mid typing. So I will be typing code, there will be a pause, a brief lock up, and all of a sudden the text I'm typing is being put in an active textbox or something.

It only happens if there is a form open in form view. If everything is open in design view, there will be a pause, a brief lock up, then the cursor is still in my VBA module.

The VBA editor does not appear to be running code when this happens. Even when I am not scripting, or doing anything, I will see the active form lose its data from list boxes briefly before repopulating. This is with no input from me. I have an idea that it may be refreshing the connection to my back end SQL Server, but I'm not sure.

I've tried searching for this problem on this and other sites and found nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I have an idea that it may be refreshing the connection to my back end SQL Server," are you using "bound controls" (i.e. form controls or components that are directly bound in their properties to a data source)

Comment: The forms themselves are not typically bound - I use a lot of unbound controls with pass through queries to input/edit data.  I have many linked tables and views. Some form controls are sourced from queries off of these.

So is there a way to control the refresh timing?